# django : get object from foreign key

Tags: django, model

Suppose following model class,

> ```
>  class Bookmark(models.Model):   
>      owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,related_name='bookmarkOwner')
>      parent = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,related_name='bookmarkParent')
>      sitter = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,related_name='bookmarkSitter')
> ```

How can I get `sitter` objects from `owner` Objects?

```
user = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=1)

UserProfile.objects.filter(bookmarkOwner=user)
```

returns empty `tuple`, and I cannot specify `sitter` variable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this, if you want to avoid using a loop:

```
pks = some_user_profile.bookmarkOwner.values_list('sitter', flat=True)
sitters = UserProfile.objects.filter(pk__in=pks).all()
```

Alternatively, you might want to experiment with setting up a many-to-many field and using the `through` parameter. See the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Comment: there is no need for `.all()` at the end of `sitters = UserProfile.objects.filter(pk__in=pks).all()`

Comment: Brilliant answer! Plus I used this method because I couldn't easily update a ManyToMany field easily

Answer (score 5):

you should do

```
objs = Bookmark.objects.filter(owner=user)
# This will return all bookmarks related to the user profile.

for obj in objs:
    print obj.owner # gives owner object
    print obj.parent # gives parent object
    print obj.sitter # gives sitter object
```

If there is only one Bookmark object for a user profile (no multiple entries). Then you should use `.get` method instead (which return a single object).

```
obj = Bookmark.objects.get(owner=user)
print obj.owner
print obj.parent
print obj.sitter
```

Comment: Thanks . But is there any other way of no-using for loop?

Comment: Is the bookmark table contains only one Bookmark object related to profile?

Comment: yes, parent can have many bookmarks, sitter can have many bookmarks,  but for one parent - one sitter pair, there is only one bookmark

Comment: please check my updated answer `how to retrieve a single object`. for one parent one sitter pair you should do `Bookmark.objects.get(owner=user, sitter=other_user)`.