# Django - Get objects from third model using foreignkey

Tags: django

I have Models.

```
class M1(models.Model):
   ....

class M2(models.Model):
   ....

class M3(models.Model):
   n1 = models.ForeignKey(
        M1, related_name="M1_related", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
  n2 = models.ForeignKey(
        M2, related_name="M2_related", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

In templates I have `M1` object. Using it, I want to get all `M2` objects related to `M1` object.

I tried `{{M1_object.M1_related.n2.all}}` but is blank.
Doing `{{M1_object.M1_related}}` gives me `M3.None`

I looked at these two questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011255/django-get-object-from-foreign-key) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383688/how-i-get-data-from-third-related-model-in-django). They are similar to mine but not helpful.

Comment: can you show the template code

Comment: Have you tried `{{M1_object.M1_related.all}}` ?

Answer (score 0):

[As Pierre mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6493001/11282077) template tags achieve this.

Firstly create the file structure. Go into the app directory where the tag is needed, and add these files:

```
templatetags
templatetags/__init__.py
templatetags/custom_query_tags.py
```

The **templatetags/custom_query_tags.py** file:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_m2_objects(M1_object_id):
    m3s = M3.objects.filter(n1__id=M1_object_id)
    new_list = []
    for each_m3 in m3s:
        new_list.append(each_m3.n2)
    return new_list
```

In the template:

```
{% load custom_query_tags %} <!--don't forget to load the custom_query_tags.py file in the template. -->


{% get_m2_objects M1_object.id as all_related_m2s %}

{% for each_m2_object in all_related_m2s %}
    <!-- Your code here -->
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can add a `ManyToManyField` with an intermediate model :

```
class M2(models.Model):
   m1_objects = models.ManyToManyField(M1, through='M3', related_name='m2_objects')
```

Then you can do :

```
{{ M1_object.m2_objects.all }}
```